# Notification on change of validation status in AWS certificate manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate

We provision SSL certificates from AWS Certificate Manager for our multiple customers. Once customer completes the validation of SSL (either by Email or DNS), we need to perform the next set of activities. Right now, we have to keep on checking in AWS web console whether SSL certificate has been validated or not. Is there any way for us to get notified (by email) once validation is successful or failed?

Comment: Have you looked into AWS Config? I know they have a way to send notifications when resources change. I haven't verified this, else I'd have put it as an answer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/example-sns-notification.html